# Syntax error on creating an computed persisted column with CASE

Tags: singlestore

I need to create a computed persisted column, which returns an BIGINT (1,2) based on the result.

```
DROP TABLE measurements;

CREATE TABLE measurements (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    status AS (
        CASE id
        WHEN (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                measurement_points
            WHERE
                measurement_points.measurement_id = measurements.id
                AND measurement_points.status IN('OK', 'ERROR')) = 3 THEN
            1
        ELSE
            2
        END) PERSISTED BIGINT 
  );
```

This returns an error

```
Query 2 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                measurement_points
            WHERE
                measurement' at line 1
```

Although the error is talking about "MySQL syntax", I am using SingleStore SingleStore DB Version: 8.1.1.

I tried to extract the SQL statement itself, which works fine:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
        CASE id
        WHEN (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                measurement_points
            WHERE
                measurement_points.measurement_id = measurements.id
                AND measurement_points.status IN('OK', 'ERROR')) = 3 THEN
            1
        ELSE
            2
        END) AS status
FROM
    measurements;
```

which results in

`Query 1 OK`

### My questions are:

1. Is SingleStore capable of doing what I want?
2. Where exactly did I make the mistake that leads to the syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

SingleStore does not support putting a subselect as the expression in a computed column. To accomplish this, you'd need to compute the select yourself when inserting the data.